# Fabric.js not loading path elements from SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

As per fabric's documentation, fabric.loadSVGFromURL will return "paths, path groups (for complex objects), images, text, and so on."

I'm trying to load [this](https://app.customily.com/Content/eps-svg/4647-08-1293-147-01-01-c7b295b3-0d40-44cc-8892-d82da1edc36b.svg) SVG that has paths and images, but fabric is only loading part of the images (but no paths whatsoever) when using this code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabricCanvas');
var svgString = "https://app.customily.com/Content/eps-svg/4647-08-1293-147-01-01-c7b295b3-0d40-44cc-8892-d82da1edc36b.svg";
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(svgString, function (objects, options) {  
        var a = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);     
    canvas.add(a).renderAll();
});
```

And this is how the SVG looks when loaded:
https://jsfiddle.net/loskiorama/L2yo3ukj/

Any idea how can I get loadSVGFromURL to successfully load all the elements form the SVG?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876146/cant-load-svg-from-url)

Comment: I'm not sure, but after looking at the source for the svg, the issue could be related to a known issue in Fabric.js. You can find more info here https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/5458

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's related to the fabric version.
This is the result I obtained using the same code, with 3.0.0:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.js

[image]

This is what I obtained with 1.4.0 (The version on the example @Ben sent):

[image]

And finally, this is how it looks like with 1.5.0 (as it should)

[image]

Looks like a fabric bug to me... anyone can shed some light and confirm this?

Comment: After researching a little bit more I found out that this issue was introduced in version 2.4.0. 
2.3.6 was the last version where I was able to see all the SVG elements. The only problem is that image elements are not transparent (there is a white box where there shouln't be any color)